# How do I add swipe-to-delete to a stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I'm trying to decide between a tableview and a stackview for part of a new project and I couldn't find anything about how to add swipe-to-delete functionality to view elements that aren't tableviews.

Is this possible? If so, how?

I'd rather not use a table view as each cell will have varying heights and I've read that they don't dynamically increase in height to accommodate content.

This will be done in Swift if it makes a difference.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell this library will help you to do all functionalities in `Tableview` swipe. Hope it may help you.